# Input.KeyDown function doesn't detect the key pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, keyboard

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("going here");

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
    {
        Debug.Log("Letter T pressed");
    }
}
```

The code only prints "going here". When I press T nothing happens
the project settings -> Player -> ActiveInputHandeling* set up in both.
The script is attached to the object.
I tried to do this in different project and it works.

Comment: Restart unity. Try again. If you mess with input you need to restart

Comment: @dodexahedron why would you edit away a typo? How do you know it is not actually present in OPs code?

Comment: Did you change the input system to use the new one? If so, `Input` will not receive events.

Comment: @derHugo because it's literally a compile error without it, so it's a pretty safe bet that it's not in their code, because the c# compiler will tell you that you're missing the semi-colon. OP's application _runs_, so that confirms the semi-colon isn't the issue. No? Or is it dynamically compiled and swallowing the compile error?

Comment: @dodexahedron it is an obvious hint though that OP's code here might not 100% reflect the actual code they are using .. wasn't a big deal this time but in general instead of directly editing it away I would prefer to ask OP and wait until they correct their posted code themselves or at least confirm that this was just a typo in here ;)

Comment: @derHugo noted. Good SOP.

Answer (score 2):

*Looking at the stated reason of your problem*,

Please kindly note that, in order to avoid future similar problems, you can make sure you are always on game view (when pressing Play button) by changing the config to `Play Focused` like below:

[image]

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer, so the question is marked answered by SO. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to click on the game screen with the mouse so it started to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can edit and mark this answer so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

I think after
Debug.Log("Letter T pressed")
you need to add ;

in Unity if there is little problem, they just show you error code, but it still work without problem code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).